# Test i Enumerables Randomly, j Times in Order

Tags: c#, loops, .net-4.0

I have an IEnumerable with i items that I need to iterate through and test against another IEnumerable with j items.  However, i should be iterated through randomly and at every iteration of j, potentially a different item from i would be tested:

```
list_of_is = [ a, b, c, d, e, f, g ]
list_of_js = [ x, y, z ]
```

Lets assume randomizing i is trivial, so we can generate something like this pretty easily:

```
random_is[x] = [ e, b, f, g, d, a, c ]
random_is[y] = [ f, b, g, c, a, d, e ]
random_is[z] = [ d, g, f, c, b, e, a ]
```

Now what we need will essentially be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list_of_is.Count(); i++)
{
   foreach (var j in list_of_js)
   {
      yield return j.DoSomething(random_is[j][i]);
   }
}
```

and the output would be:

e<sub>x</sub>, f<sub>y</sub>, d<sub>z</sub>, b<sub>x</sub>, b<sub>y</sub>, g<sub>z</sub>, ...

Now, is there any way to do this without storing the `random_is` variable?  Both lists are very large and this would consume a huge amount of memory.

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, the ordering is important.  Each pass of j should only "process" the next item in it's random_i.  Overall, the processing should be completed in the following order:

[image]

Comment: So you are asking how to get a random permutation of `list_of_is`? Also, the example code does not match the sample output.

Comment: No, more like trying to iterate through multiple random permutations in order.  What does not match in the sample output?

Comment: Well, if you can permute then multiple permutations are just a `for` loop. The sample output's elements are more than the `j`s.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right.  The output is correct, the code is not.  Example code has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get around the problem is to swap your loops. That is:

```
foreach (var j in list_of_js)
{
    random_i = generateRandom(j);
    for (int i = 0; i < list_of_is.Count(); ++i)
    {
        return j.DoSomething(random_i[i]);
    }
}
```

Although looking at the code, that `return` is going to kill the loop. Perhaps you meant `yield return`?

In any case, this makes it necessary to generate each random list only once, and you only need one `random_is` collection in memory at a time. It does, however, change the order in which things are generated. That's not a problem if you can save the intermediate values and rearrange after all values have been generated.

Comment: This would likely accomplish the same thing, but the order output would be different.  With the sample above, it would output: ex, bx, fx, ..., fy, by, gy, ... whereas I need it to output ex, fy, dz, bx, by, gz, ...

Comment: @Adam: Yes, the order would be different, as I said in my last paragraph. The question is whether you can buffer the intermediate values and then re-order on output.

Comment: It would be possible to re-order on output using the proposed solution, but the reason it needed to be in order is because the outer loop has a sliding window and should never run to completion

Answer (score 1):

You can't really randomize a Enumerable unless you convert it to an array first, because an enumerator by definition gets 1 value at a time, token by token.

So, if I understand correctly, I would do something like this...

1. Convert list_of_is to an array
2. For each j in list_of_js
3. Loop through list_of_is performing Fisher-Yates shuffle
4. Loop through list_of_is and do f(j,i) where i is the current index in the shuffle

Here's a quick example, I hope this helps (sorry fixed some errors)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static IEnumerable<char> list_of_is = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};
        static IEnumerable<char> list_of_js = new char[] { 'x', 'y', 'z' };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string result in Randomize())
                Debug.Write(result);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<String> Randomize()
        {
            char[] random_is = list_of_is.ToArray();
            int jCount = list_of_js.Count();

            Random r = new Random();

            // foreach j
            foreach(char j in list_of_js)
            {
                // create a random ordering of is
                for (int i = random_is.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    int x = r.Next(0, i);

                    // swap
                    char temp = random_is[x];
                    random_is[x] = random_is[i];
                    random_is[i] = temp;
                }

                // now evaluate the random pairs
                foreach(Char i in random_is)
                    yield return String.Format("{0}{1} ", Char.ToUpper(i), j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
Gx Cx Ex Bx Fx Ax Dx Dy By Fy Ay Cy Gy Ey Bz Az Gz Cz Fz Ez Dz
```

**Edit:**
Actually, it just hit me that your pseudocode doesn't quite seem right. You are generating 3 random arrays of 7 values.. and then wanting to output pairs of X,Y,Z for each of the random arrays. It seems like yoou would need 3 * 7 * 3  = 63 ouputs then..

Therefore, this may be more accurate:

```
public static IEnumerable<String> Randomize()
{
    char[] random_is = list_of_is.ToArray();
    int jCount = list_of_js.Count();

    Random r = new Random();

    // foreach j
    for (int random = 0; random < jCount; random++)
    {
        // create a random ordering of is
        for (int i = random_is.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int x = r.Next(0, i);

            // swap
            char temp = random_is[x];
            random_is[x] = random_is[i];
            random_is[i] = temp;
        }

        // now evaluate the random pairs
        foreach (Char i in random_is)
            foreach(Char j in list_of_js)
                yield return String.Format("{0}{1} ", Char.ToUpper(i), j);
    }
}
```

And it outputs:

```
Cx Cy Cz Gx Gy Gz Dx Dy Dz Bx By Bz Fx Fy Fz Ax Ay Az Ex Ey Ez Bx By Bz Cx Cy Cz Fx Fy Fz Ax Ay Az Ex Ey Ez Dx Dy Dz Gx Gy Gz Cx Cy Cz Ax Ay Az Bx By Bz Gx Gy Gz Fx Fy Fz Ex Ey Ez Dx Dy Dz
```

Comment: Thanks but the solution uses the same random array with each x,y,z pair.  The main issue is being able to generate x,y,z pairs using different random permutations

Comment: What now? How is that different?

Comment: Because all x,y,z's process the same random list.  The difference is that each x,y,z should process the same list in a different random order.